# Need to extract code of a bash script function from python

Tags: python, bash, shell

So I have a Bash script which I am trying to parse from python.
How can I get the contents/code of a function using python 
**Eg:**

```
my_function() {
echo "SO is awesome";
}
```

So i need `echo "SO is awesome";`

Comment: use `subprocess.call('bash command')`

Comment: I don't need to execute the code I need the contents of the function as in the text

Comment: If you need to handle more complex cases you will have to write a real bash parser, if you need just this type of example, just read the file and when you find `my_function() {` start "recording" and stop when you get to `}`

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I need to do Is there any python module to do this stuff?

Comment: *Why* do you need this? Sounds like an XY problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> script = '''\
... my_function() {
... echo "SO is awesome";
... }'''
>>> contents = script[1+script.find('{'):script.rfind('}')].strip()
>>> contents
'echo "SO is awesome";'
```

Look for the first left brace and the last right brace. All bets are off if there's a nested function!

Comment: This helps but will only work for The Eg. I gave but the actual script it pretty complicated.Is there any python module for parsing Bash?

Comment: Possibly a fringe concern, but not every function body is delimited by braces. `f () ( echo foo )` is legal. So is `f () for x in 1 2 3; do echo "$x"; done`.

Comment: Braces can also occur anywhere inside the body of the function without defining nested functions: `f () { { read a; read b; } < somefile; echo "$a = $b"; }`.

Comment: Good that you mention these points. It's many years since I used bash.